# Can JFrog Xray scan only Maven artifact?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

Can JFrog Xray be used to scan Maven artifact directly? All examples and resources I can find shows only Xray scanning Docker Images where it also scans layer with java application and its dependencies.

But can one scan Maven artifact directly even if its not part of any Docker images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can se in the official [JFrog Xray](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Xray) documentation, it supports many more technologies. NPM, NuGet, Docker and RPM just to name a few.

The artifacts are scanned regardless of what contains them, as long as they are hosted in a JFrog Artifactory repository that is configured to be scanned by Xray.

BTW, scanning is recursive, so if you have an NPM module in an RPM, it would also be scanned and reported.